# What HD are compatible to the Alesis HD24 Recorder?

Tags: hardware

Can any hard-drives be bought and configured to work in the caddies inside this unit?

Or do you have to use a specific kind manufactured by Alesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manufacturers website](http://alesis.com/hd24):

> Caddies can be fitted with IDE/EIDE/ATA drive at 5,400/7,200/10,000 RPM up to 2TB

This means that you can get a drive from anywhere, but it only accepts the older PATA drives.  Currently [New Egg still has a few](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007603%20600003442&IsNodeId=1&name=IDE%20Ultra%20ATA100%20/%20ATA-6) at < $100USD.

Any brand of drive will do, but I would recommend either Seagate or Western Digital.

Comment: Ditto on Seagate and Western Digital. Many years of servicing will back me up.